# Get zabuto_calendar options

Tags: calendar

I use plugin **zabuto_calendar**(https://github.com/zabuto/calendar).

```
$("#calendar").zabuto_calendar({
    language: "ru",
    show_previous: true,
    show_next: true,
    cell_border: true,
    today: true,
    show_days: true,
    weekstartson: 1,
    nav_icon: {
        prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>',
        next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>'
    },
    ajax: {
        url: "/cabinet/info/show_calendar_data.php",
        modal: true
    }
});
```

It's need update calendar when select input changed. I must to add new GET parameter "category", which is select input's value, in `ajaxSettings.url`.

How can I get `$("#calendar")` options?